# Postgres select concatenated column name

Tags: postgresql

For the sake of example, there's five columns in a table `month`:

- month.week1
- month.week2
- month.week3
- month.week4
- month.week5

The number of `col` is determined by a function

`EXTRACT(WEEK FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW())) + 1`

How can I select the column `colX`? This is what I have so far

```
SELECT month.week || (
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM NOW()) 
    - EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW())) + 1
)::text 
FROM month
```

But that gives me the error

> ERROR: column month.week doesn't exist
>   SQL state: 42703

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use case statement

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (week expresion) = 1 THEN month.week1
         WHEN (week expresion) = 2 THEN month.week2
         WHEN (week expresion) = 3 THEN month.week3
         WHEN (week expresion) = 4 THEN month.week4
         ELSE month.week5
    END as WeekValue
FROM month
```

OR

```
SELECT
    CASE (week expresion) 
         WHEN 1 THEN month.week1
         WHEN 2 THEN month.week2
         WHEN 3 THEN month.week3
         WHEN 4 THEN month.week4
         ELSE month.week5
    END as WeekValue
FROM month
```

Comment: Or just `CASE (week expression) WHEN 1 THEN ... WHEN 2 ...` to avoid repeating the (really long) week expression.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic sql sample:

```
t=# create table so58(i int,w1 text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create or replace function so59(_n int) returns table (i int,w text) as $$begin
return query execute format('select i,w%s from so58',_n);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select * from so59(1);
 i | w
---+---
(0 rows)
```